# Route not found in custom form request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I use laravel custom form request with command `php artisan make:request AddressBookRequest` 
And use that request in my controller like :

```
public function add_address_book($lang,$user_id,AddressBookRequest $request){
 dd($request);
}
```

And when i run api route laravel shows :

```
 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

But when i change that `AddressBookRequest` to `Request` like :

```
 public function add_address_book($lang,$user_id,Request $request){
 dd($request);
}
```

Api works fine

AddressBookRequest :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

 use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class AddressBookRequest extends Request
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
          return [
              'title' => 'required',
              'address' => 'required',
              'latitude' => 'required',
              'longitude' => 'required'
          ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
              'title.required' => trans('address_book.title_required'),
              'address.required' => trans('address_book.address_required'),
              'latitude.required' => trans('address_book.latitude_required'),
              'longitude.required' => trans('address_book.longitude_required'),
    ];
}


}
```

AddressBookController usecases:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Aggregate\Address_book\Controller\v1_0;

 use App\Http\Requests\AddressBookRequest;
 use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
 use EventHomes\Api\ApiController;
 use JWTAuth;

 class AddressBookController extends BaseController
 {
```

And route :

```
  Route::group(['namespace' => 'Aggregate\Address_book\Controller\v1_0', 'middleware' => 'jwt.auth', 'prefix' => 'api/v1.0/{lang}'], function () {
   Route::post('customer/{id}/address_book', 'AddressBookController@add_address_book');
  });
```

How can i fix it to use custom request?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Add this to top of controller file **use App\Http\Requests\AddressBookRequest;**

Comment: I added but it still does not work

Comment: What error you are getting now ?

Comment: Check if your request directory path is **App\Http\Requests\AddressBookRequest**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by adding :

```
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
 use EventHomes\Api\ApiController;

 abstract class Request extends FormRequest
 {
    use ApiController;

    public function response(array $errors)
    {
       foreach($errors as $key=>$error)
       {
         return $this->respondUnprocessable(1004,'validation',$errors[$key][0]);
       }
    }

}
```

In `requst.php`

Answer (score 2):

You should add this line to the top of the controller:

```
use App\Http\Requests\AddressBookRequest;
```

Also, make sure `authorize()` method inside custom request class returns `true`:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get now? Please show route you use.

Comment: same error ,  route : `Route::group(['namespace' => 'Aggregate\Address_book\Controller\v1_0', 'middleware' => 'jwt.auth', 'prefix' => 'api/v1.0/{lang}'], function () {
    Route::post('customer/{id}/address_book', 'AddressBookController@add_address_book');
});`